# Symfony + doctrine : select clause where don't work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.3

Clause where not working on a simple array type.
The condition is **cc.isActive = :active**

```
return $qb->select('c')
        ->from('Win4uAdminBundle:ColorGammeCor', 'c')
        ->innerJoin('Win4uAdminBundle:Color', 'cc')
        ->where('c.type = :type')
        ->andWhere('cc.isActive = :active ')
        ->andWhere('c.gamme = :gamme_id')
        ->addGroupBy('c.colorExt')
        ->setParameter('type', $type)
        ->setParameter('active', 1)
        ->setParameter('gamme_id', $gammeId)
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Here the filed definition :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="simple_array", columnDefinition="TINYINT(1) NULL")
 */
private $isActive;
```

If the content of the field is_active is null, this query return the records... why? I ask only is_active = 1

Many thanks

Comment: Did you try debugging "runnable query" from symfony profiler? I don't know why you're using simple_array type instead boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always debug the actual SQL Doctrine is calling by executing `$qb->getQuery()->getSQL()` where `$qb` is your QueryBuilder object, or by looking at the Symfony toolbar.

There's two issues with the code. Firstly, the definition of the `$isActive` field is wrong, it should be a boolean rather than a simple_array:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
 */
private $isActive;
```

Secondly, the innerJoin should [specify the relation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods) on `Win4uAdminBundle:ColorGammeCor`, so it should be something similar to:

```
return $qb->select('c')
    ->from('Win4uAdminBundle:ColorGammeCor', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('c.color', 'cc')
```

Comment: Hello, correcting my innerJoin and debugging with ->getSQL() help me to resolve my issue. Thanks a lot.

Also using "isActive" as simple array help my to use it as a checkbox. May be a symfony beginner error...

So thanks guys